# How can I track my location in a web map using LeafletJS/Mapbox?

Tags: geolocation, leaflet, mapbox

In a recent project I had to implement a geolocation tracking feature for a web app that shows users' data on a map powered by LeafletJS/Mapbox. The Leaflet [doc for "map.locate()" API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate) and the ["watch" locate option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-watch) is helpful but I couldn't find a good example of how they worked together, or what the continuous location tracking looks like using Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a good example of this anywhere, I decided to create my own. Try the working web app on your mobile device. Hope this helps others.

```
var marker, circle;

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    if(marker) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
    }

    if(circle) {
        map.removeLayer(circle);
    }                

    marker = L.marker(e.latlng);
    circle = L.circle(e.latlng, radius);

    marker.addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    circle.addTo(map);            
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

map.locate({setView: true, 
            maxZoom: 20,
           watch: true,
           enableHighAccuracy: true,
           maximumAge: 15000,
           timeout: 3000000});
```

The working app http://jsfiddle.net/hanislovingit/7n2wf0kg/12

Comment: In your jsfiddle, what string should I use in my website instead of  " **hanislovingit.kep5bm68** "  `var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'hanislovingit.kep5bm68');` In mapbox website I see `mapbox.streets` what is it?

Comment: I think that string 'hanislovingit.kep5bm68' was my test project name in my Mapbox account. You can create your own project in your Mapbox account and use that. BTW, if you are considering using Mapbox for the browser, use the new MapboxGL.js which utilizes the client machine's graphics card for much better performance.